# How do I keep Google from indexing my redirect domains?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, dns

I have five domains redirecting to my main site. I originally setup these redirect domains because many people in my target demographic are not very computer literate, and I worried they would mis-spell or mis-type the site name. I want to do what Google does with gogle.com and their other domains.

```
exampledomains.com <-- Main Site
exampledomains.net
exampledomains.org
exampledomain.com
exampledomain.net
exampledomain.org
```

Now I'm seeing that Google is indexing about 3000 results for each redirect domain, and I'm worried it's going to hurt my SEO.

My host setup the domains with the same IP as my main site, then put non-masking redirects in the .htaccess. The sites do not have their own accounts on the server, so I can't setup a separate htaccess or robots.txt as their presently configured. How should I set this up?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.exampledomains\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.exampledomains.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I failed to mention, I serve everything over https and force www.

Do I do this for each domain? If not, then this is in there now. Do I need to do anything to change it to https and www, aside from modifying the second URL? 

`Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.exampledomains.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.exampledomains.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]`

Comment: If so, then this is what the host added for each, then commented out for some reason: 

`#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^exampledomain\.com$ [OR]
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.exampledomain\.com$
#RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/www\.exampledomain\.com" [R=301,L]`

Comment: Thank you, and sorry if I'm being dense here, I just want to verify. Would I add one entry for each of my domains, to the .htaccess **of the main/target site**?

Comment: @BigIron this will redirect everything **except** the www.exampledomains.com domain